# What does the 'which' in 'after which refers to?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> at one time the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts, **after which** the fragments rejoined through mutual gravitational attraction.

I understand the sentence can be re-arrange as below:

> at one time the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts,
> **which** the fragments rejoined through mutual gravitational attraction **after**.

Can someone explain to me what does 'which' refers to here? I was told that 'which' cannot be use to refer to the whole clause so can the 'which' used here refers to the preceding clause? Or does it refers to 'the surface?

Thank you.

Comment: It's "after" ***the time at which** the surface broke apart*. In principle, that key word "time" could be included in the original text: *the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts, **after which time** the fragments rejoined through mutual gravitational attraction*. But if you want to think of it as *...after which **impacts...,*** that would amount to the same thing anyway.

Comment: In non-defining relatives (like the one in your example), the antecedent can be virtually anything: words, phrases, clauses, even whole sentences. In your example, I'd say that he antecedent of "which" is "the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts".

Comment: Think of it as "after R the fragments rejoined through mutual gravitational attraction", where R is interpreted as the the breaking apart of the surface ... "

Comment: *Which* refers to the entire first clause: _At one time the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts. After [**that event**] the fragments rejoined through mutual gravitational attraction._ --> _At one time the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts, after [**which**] the fragments rejoined through mutual gravitational attraction._

Comment: In 'The surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts, after which the station's impulse recorder broke' the antecedent of 'which' is indeterminate. But here, only the clausal antecedent reading makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It means "everything we described in the part of the sentence preceding the word *after*."

As in:

> At one time the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts,
> after which [i.e. after the surface broke apart as a result of
> repeated impacts] the fragments rejoined through mutual gravitational
> attraction.

Comment: The explanation being? In 'the surface broke apart as a result of repeated impacts, after which the station's impulse recorder broke' the antecedent of 'which' is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever event is being referenced that precedes "after which". "Which" is used to indicate a distinction being made between two or more things being discussed. The first thing would be the one "which" came before the next thing (the thing that comes "after")